# Save OpenAI response in Azure function to Blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I used blob trigger template to create an Azure function that is triggered by new file updated in Azure blob storage. I am using python v2 to create Azure function in VScode. My issue is not able to store openai result into a new blob file. I noticed my function didn't have a function.json file. I am not sure if this is the problem for my issue. I tried redeploy couple times still didn't create a function.json.

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import os
import openai
import PyPDF2
import io
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_version = "2023-05-15" 
openai.api_base = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_BASE")  # Your Azure OpenAI resource's endpoint value.
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="mypath/{name}",
                               connection="<My_BLOB_CONNECTION_SETTING>") 
@app.blob_trigger_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="openai-outputs/text.txt",
                                connection="<My_BLOB_CONNECTION_SETTING>")
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(io.BytesIO(myblob.read()))
    text = ""
    for page in pdf_reader.pages:
        text += page.extract_text()

    logging.info(
                f"textyyy: {text}")
    messages= [
       # my prompt
    ]

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        engine="testing3",
        messages=messages
    )
    
    logging.info(f"response1111: {response}"
                f"response['choices'][0]['message']['content']: {response['choices'][0]['message']['content']}")
    
    outputblob.set(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
```

i followed this [azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python) to write the above code. It started failed to deploy to Azure function portal.

Comment: Python V2 doesn't have function.json file.

Comment: I talked to the Azure customer service, he insisted the file will be automatically generated.

Comment: you want to save the generated file in the blob storage?

Comment: yes, after I started adding this line ```@app.blob_trigger_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="openai-outputs/text.txt",
                                connection="<My_BLOB_CONNECTION_SETTING>")``` and ```outputblob```, the code started failed and failed to deploy to azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to save the response of the OpenAI to blob storage using this code.

I also used python v2. In python V2 `function.json` file are not available. Binding is created using `@app.blob_trigger` for trigger binding, `@app.blob_input` for input binding,`@app.blob_output`for output binding.

`PyPDF2` package is used to work with `.pdf`  files and perform operation on the file.

I have used `@app.blob_trigger` to trigger the function code, `@app.blob_input` to read the content of the file and `@app.blob_output` to modify the file.

**`function_app.py`:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import os
import openai
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_BASE")
openai.api_version = "2023-07-01-preview"
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="response",
                               connection="BlobStorageConnectionString")
@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob",path="response/hello.txt",connection="BlobStorageConnectionString")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="output",path="chatgpt-conversation/conversation.txt",connection="BlobStorageConnectionString2")
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream, inputblob: str, output:func.Out[bytes]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    content= inputblob
    logging.info(f"Contentof the file is : {content}")

    ai_responses=[]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        engine="test_chatgpt",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."},
            {"role":"user","content": content}
        ])
    ai_responses.append(f"Input: {content}\nResponse: {response['choices'][0]['message']['content']}\n\n")
    logging.info(ai_responses)
    output.set("\n".join(ai_responses))
```

**`local.settings.json`**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "OPENAI_API_BASE":"https://<xxxxxx>.openai.azure.com/",
    "OPENAI_API_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "BlobStorageConnectionString":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "BlobStorageConnectionString2":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

**`Input`:**

[image]

**`Output`:**

[image]

[image]